# Socket.close() have no effect during Socket.connect()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Using the default socket implementation on Windows, I was not able to find any effective method to stop `Socket.connect()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5395353/499922) suggests `Thread.interrupt()` will not work, but `Socket.close()` will. However, in my trial, the latter didn't work either.

My goal is to terminate the application quickly and cleanly (i.e. clean up work needs to be done after the socket termination). I do not want to use the timeout in `Socket.connect()` because the process can be killed before a reasonable timeout has expired.

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ComTest {
    static Socket s;
    static Thread t;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        s = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", 11);
        p(addr);
        t = Thread.currentThread();
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(4000);
                    p("Closing...");
                    s.close();
                    p("Closed");
                    t.interrupt();
                    p("Interrupted");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        s.connect(addr);
    }

    static void p(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/10.1.1.1:11
Closing...
Closed
Interrupted
(A few seconds later)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
```

Comment: *Why* are you trying to close a socket during connect? If it's to impose a connect timeout, you can do that with the API.

Comment: @EJP This is a business application where every operation needs to be atomic. However, it runs on tomcat where the stop command has a timeout. If the socket happens to be in the connect call when the tomcat shuts down, we found that the clean up code in the socket thread does not run.

Comment: So you shouldn't do anything that needs cleaning up afterwards until you have the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fork the thread and then the main thread is trying to make the connection to the remote server.  The socket is not yet connected so I suspect `s.close()` does nothing on a socket that is not connected.  It's hard to see what the INET socket implementation does here.  `t.interrupt();` won't work because the `connect(...)` is not interruptible.

You could use the NIO `SocketChannel.connect(...)` which looks to be interruptible.  Maybe something like:

```
SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
// this can be interrupted
boolean connected = sc.connect(t.address);
```

Not sure if that would help though.

Comment: Yeah, that is my guess as well. However, there must be some alternative implementation that can be killed...

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems one of the major advantage of SocketChannel is the ability to stop `connect()`. I'll give it a try later, but I believe it is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it seems the API requires you to use a Selector to really have a easy to interrupt behavior (i.e. if the channel is non-blocking, then you need a selector to know when it is actually connected). Otherwise will have to spin on `SocketChannel.finishConnect()`. Temporarily unmark as answer to see if other people have better alternatives (unlikely though :[ ).